# How to restart sticky service after power saver kills it on android

Tags: android, service, process

I tried by setting `android:isolatedProcess="true"` but it's not working

actually I want to show a permanent notification all time

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceIcon/*R.mipmap.ic_launcher*/))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_flo_not)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setOngoing(onGoing)
                .setAutoCancel(autoCancelable)
                .setPriority(priority)
                .setContentText(message);
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (playSound)
            mBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
        if (remoteViews == null) {
            // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, resultClass);
            resultIntent.setAction(action);

            // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
            // started Activity.
            // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
            // your application to the Home screen.
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setContent(remoteViews);
        }
```

Comment: You need to start service again from your Application.

Comment: @ChetanJoshi  how can i that because power saver/battery saver kills my app.

Answer (score 1):

Override onTaskRemoved() in your service and use alarm manager to start the service again. Below is code .

```
    @Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    Log.d(TAG, "TASK REMOVED");

    PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(),
            1001,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000, service);
}
```

Comment: Already done this thing but not working after starting power saver/battery saver

Comment: When it comes to power saver , Android OS forcefully closes many process you can't do any thing about that, it even closes some of its process

Comment: there are few apps handling this issue ex. My Data Manager https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=en

Comment: @GOURAVMEHTA
The above mentioned App(Data Manager) handles this issue only when there was the Data turned ON before activating Super Power saving mode, otherwise it fails to restart the service after turning off the the Super Power saving mode.

Answer (score 1):

Service.START_STICKY service are those which are restarted if they are terminated due to some reason.You just need to return Service.START_STICKY from onStartCommand

`public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      return START_STICKY;
      }`

You just need to do above, There is no separate thing that you have to do

Comment: can you share code snippet.what you are doing in service may be it is keeps on restarting

Answer (score 0):

The service **does** get re-created, **not** re-started.
If you override the `onCreate` and do a Log.d or a Toast, you will see that onCreate gets called after your activity and app is destroyed.

So the trick to keep it running after it is re-created is to do your code on the `onCreate` method and use the `onStartCommand` just to `return START_STICKY`.

---

Another thing to notice (and since I can't comment, I'd like to add to Abdul Kawee answer with the `AlarmManager`):
It is SOLVED on api27: all you have to do is move your `super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)` to be the last line of code.

I have found that destructive methods should only call super in the end of the overriden method, otherwise some resources are no longer available in runtime.